# What is the difference between 응용하다 and 운용하다?

Tags: word-usage

I understand them both as "to apply", although the dictionary says `응용` is "practical application." Are they more or less interchangeable? I would be particularly interested to hear cases where one can be used but the other can not be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**응용하다 (應用--)[응ː용하다]**
[동사] 어떤 이론이나 이미 얻은 지식을 구체적인 개개의 사례나 다른 분야의 일에 적용하여 이용하다.

응용하다 means "To apply a theory or knowledge to something different, especially in a practical thing" If you learn mathematics and use your mathematical knowledge to something practical, such as data science, you can say "나는 내 수학적 지식을 데이터 과학 분야에 **응용**하였다"

**운용하다 (運用--)[우ː뇽하다]**

운용하다 means "To operate or manage something". You can operate resources, robots, servers, etc. 운용하다 can be used like this; 그는 자원을 효율적으로 **운용**한다. (He manages resources efficiently.)

These two words are different a lot. So in many cases, they are barely interchangeable.

Comment: Great examples!

Answer (score 1):

응용 is more like used with concept, knowledge, principle. Also it is in wide use than 운용. 응용 often connotes adding better/different idea to the original one. For example, after I learned my mom's recipe and then I could develop the recipe. At that time I can say I 응용하다 my mom's recipe.

운용 could be more combined with asset system or policy.  Especially it is often used in the banking industry and governemnt. When securities company managed(operate) their funds/investment, you can say the company 운용하다 their money.